# PHP method to determine if total course unit registered is not above limit unit

Tags: php, arrays

I have a form where students need to register courses for a semester, everything is working fine but the problem am facing now is how to prevent student register more than certain unit for a semester.

This is my html code

```
<form id="course" name="coursereg" method="POST" action="">

<table class="table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Select Course</th>
                 <th>Course Title</th>
                <th>Course Code</th>
                <th>Course Unit</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

                <?php
             //This is generated from the query not written here
             while($rowcourse = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){                
            $courseunit = $rowcourse['courseunit'];
            $coursename = $rowcourse['coursename'];
            $coursecode = $rowcourse['coursecode'];
                    ?>
                    <div class="form-group"> 
                  <tr>
                  <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="courses[]" id="course" 
      value="<?php echo $coursename|$coursecode|$courseunit;?>" width="80px">

                  </td>

                  <td>
                  <input type="text" name="coursename[]" id="course" value=" 
         <?php echo $coursename;?>" style="border:none; background- 
           color:transparent; width:350px">
                  </td>

                  <td>
                  <input type="text" name="coursecode[]" id="course" value=" 
           <?php echo $coursecode;?>" style="border:none; background- 
          color:transparent; width:120px">
                  </td>

                  <td>
                  <input type="text" name="courseunit[]" id="course" value=" 
            <?php echo $courseunit;?>" style="border:none; background- 
         color:transparent; width:80px">
                     </td>
                </tr>
                </div>
              <?php
               }

              ?>

        </tbody>
    </table>
      </form>
```

This is code used to process form.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['courses'])) {
        echo "<script>
            alert('Error: Select appropriate course(s) you want to register');
            window.location.href='course_registration.php';
        </script>";
    } else {
        $totalunit = 0;

        foreach($_POST['courses'] as $rows => $courses) {
            $coursename = $_POST['coursename'][$rows];
            $coursecode = $_POST['coursecode'][$rows];
            $courseunit = $_POST['courseunit'][$rows];
            $totalunit += $courseunit;

            if ($totalunit > 10){
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                    alert('Courses registered should not be more than 10 Credits');
                    window.location.href='course_registration.php';
                </script>";
            }

            $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO courses(courseunit, coursename, coursecode) VALUES (?,?,?)");
            $stmt->bind_param("sss", $courseunit, $coursename, $coursecode);

            if ($stmt->execute()) {
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                    alert('Successfully registered!');
                </script>";
            } else {
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
                    alert('Registration failed ! Contact College administrator') 
                </script>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Courses registered successfully irrespective of whether number of unit greater than 10 but it works if I used less than certain smaller number.
I need help on how to make it echo false if it is more than 10 unit

Comment: isnt this the line that prevents users from adding more then a certain amount? `if($totalunit > 24){`

Comment: Well if it is, its still doing the rest as its that is not wrapped with an else block. its also all in the loop, this is hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

Not fully understanding where this question is going but I'm guessing you want to check for the total amount of `$_POST['courseunit']` before going in to the loop.

There are two things you can count here, the amount of rows `count($_POST['courseunit'])`. Or if you want to sum up all values in the array. You can use `array_sum($_POST['courseunit'])`.

This also means you can move the `$totalunit > 24` or is this the 10? outside the loop and only put things in the database it is ok;

```php
$totalunit = array_sum($_POST['courseunit']); // or maybe the count?
if ($totalunit > 10) {
    // show an error message about the number being too high.
} else {
    foreach (...) {
        // put in database
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the limit 10 then why did you use 24 here? Also, here is your solution. If you want that no database insertion should take place if it is more than 10 then you can simply `exit()` from the script. Place the below code outside the FOR LOOP.

```
// Here change 24 to 10 first
if($totalunit > 10){
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Courses registered should not be more than 10 
  Credits');window.location.href='course_registration.php';</script>";

  exit(); // Exit function stops the script from executing further.
}
```

That is your solution. Also note that you should not use `<script>` method to display messages. The way you code the script is not good. Should I rectify your whole script? Let me know in the comments.

**EDIT**

As requested, here is how your script be written with simple, clean and elegant coding. Try this code and let me know if you face any difficulty. Also, make sure to note down the difference between your and mind coding methods. Always try to keep your codes cleaner and shorter.

```
<?php
$msg = null;

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  if(empty($_POST['courses'])){
    $msg = "Error: Select appropriate course(s) you want to register.";
  }else{
    $checked_arr = $_POST['courses'];
    $totalunit = count($checked_arr);

    if($totalunit > 10){
      $msg = "Courses registered should not be more than 10 Credits";
    }else{
      foreach($_POST['courses'] as $rows=>$courses){
        $coursename = $_POST['coursename'][$rows];
        $coursecode = $_POST['coursecode'][$rows];
        $courseunit = $_POST['courseunit'][$rows];

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO courses(courseunit, coursename, coursecode)VALUES(:unit, :name, :code)");
        $stmt-> bindValue(':unit', $courseunit);
        $stmt-> bindValue(':name', $coursename);
        $stmt-> bindValue(':code', $coursecode);
        $stmt-> execute();
      }
      if($stmt){
        $msg = "Registered successfully!";
      }else{
        $msg = "Sorry, something went wrong. Please refresh the page and try again.";
      }
    }
  }
}
?>
<!-- Display message this way in HTML part -->
<div class="message"><?php if($msg != null){ echo $msg; } ?></div>
```

Comment: I think that will be better so as to learn more because am still a beginner. Thanks

Comment: I was able to check if that condition was met by placing it outside for loop but only one value inserted into the database

Comment: Can you submit your HTML part of the code? I need to have a look at it.

Comment: Okay, I will submit it now